# Elasticsearch return specific index in array (_source field)

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got a problem with returning only specific elements of an array.

Query looks like this at the moment:

```
GET /processdata/_search
{
  "query": {"match_all": {}}, 
  "_source": "data.cells"
  "size": 1
}
```

My response is (3 similar data entries with cells array):

```
...
"_source": {
      "data": [
        {
          "cells": [
            {
              "temp": 33,
              "volt": 12
            },
            {
              "temp": 40,
              "volt": 13
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "cells": [
            {
              "temp": 34, <-- THIS IS THE VALUE I NEED
              "volt": 12
            },
            {
              "temp": 40,
              "volt": 13
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "cells": [
            {
              "temp": 35,
              "volt": 12
            },
            {
              "temp": 40,
              "volt": 13
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Now I want to retrieve only data of the **second "data" object** in the "data" array. And in this "data" object I'd like to select the **"temp" value of the first "cell" entry** of the "cells" array.

I tried something like this:

```
GET /processdata/_search
{
  "query": {"match_all": {}}, 
  "_source": "data[1].cells[0].temp",
  "size": 1
```

}

Comment: You always want to return 2nd doc?

Comment: This is only 1 doc because of Limit 1. But one doc can contain multiple „data“ objects.

Comment: Yeah, i mean which of data objects you want? always 2nd?

Comment: In this case yes. It‘s always the second.

Comment: @Mysterion: do you have an idea how to solve this problem? As posted before it's always the second entry

Comment: It’s not straightforward for sure, i would recommend you to do transformation on the client side